# Why when I'm using printf program do not send string to output, but when I use println it does?

Tags: recursion, clojure

Having simple function in Clojure

```
(defn command []
 (loop []
 (let [input (read-line)
    string-tokens (string/split input #" ")
    tokens (map keyword string-tokens)
    cmd (first tokens)]
  (cond
   ;; explain the commands
   (= cmd :help)(do
                  (printf "Usage:\nsearch <term>\nquit\n")
                  (recur)
                  )
   ;; break the loop
   (= cmd :quit) (printf "bye bye")
   ;; do something
   (= cmd :search) (do
                    (printf "Searching for %s...\n" (rest string-tokens))
                    (recur))
   ;; handle unknown input
   :else (do
          (println "Huh?")
          (recur))
 )
))
```

)

when I use `println` to send string to output it works fine, but when I'm use 'printf` it looks like string is held in buffer and printed when I exit program by chosing :quit option.

I think this has something to do with `do` block and recursion, but without it I can't use `recur` as I receive "can only recur from tail position" error.

EDIT: It's not that my program is not working. I found the way to obey the problem by first use `format` and then `println` (eg. `(println (format "Searching for %s...\n" (rest string-tokens)))`), but such a behaviour is weird for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `println` calls `flush` function, while `printf` doesnt. So if you add `(flush)` after every `printf` call, it will work.

```
(printf "Usage:\nsearch <term>\nquit\n")
(flush)
(recur)
```

i would propose you to rewrite the whole function the following way:

```
(defn command []
  (loop []
    (let [input (read-line)
          string-tokens (clojure.string/split input #" ")
          cmd (keyword (first string-tokens))
          reply (case cmd
                  :help "Usage:\nsearch <term>\nquit"
                  :quit "bye bye"
                  :search (format "Searching for %s..." (rest string-tokens))
                  "Huh?")]
      (println reply)
      (when-not (= :quit cmd)
        (recur)))))
```

so you can separate reply selection logic from function's output and recursion/termination logic. as a bonus you avoid repetition, and improve readability (well, imo)

Comment: Would you recommend to use your way or the way I added in edit (`println (format "Searching for %s...\n" (rest string-tokens)))`), with use of `format`?

Comment: in fact i would rather rewrite the whole function a bit.. Will update my answer.